# what to include?

Tags: forms

I am writing my own PHP program on root or inside a module which is suppose to return the registration form. The content of the abc.php program is:

```
<?php
  $form1=drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  $output1 = drupal_render($form1);
  echo $output1;
?>
```

this is called by a jQuery function actually and the result is to be inserted in a popup DIV. But it gives me the the error:

> undefind function drupal_get_form.

What do I need to include in the file so this error disappears?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on where you put the PHP file. Generally speaking, in Drupal you don't create a file that bootstrap Drupal, but you normally create a module or a theme, which is invoked by Drupal after it has been bootstrapped, or when the boot is still not completed (that is the case of the `hook_boot()` implementations).

- Inside the directory of a module: As you have a module, all you have to do is be sure the file is included when the module is running. That is something Drupal automatically do, if the [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) implementation is similar to the following one (it is the actual implementation made from the Book module). When, the users access "admin/content/book/settings," Drupal loads the book.admin.inc contained in the directory containing the book.module file.

```
function book_menu() {
  $items['admin/content/book'] = array(
    'title' => 'Books', 
    'description' => "Manage your site's book outlines.", 
    'page callback' => 'book_admin_overview', 
    'access arguments' => array('administer book outlines'), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'file' => 'book.admin.inc',
  );
  $items['admin/content/book/list'] = array(
    'title' => 'List', 
    'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
  );
  $items['admin/content/book/settings'] = array(
    'title' => 'Settings', 
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', 
    'page arguments' => array('book_admin_settings'), 
    'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'weight' => 8, 
    'file' => 'book.admin.inc',
  );

  // …
}
```

- In the root directory of Drupal: There are some files that are used from Drupal for various purposes, such as update.php, xmlrpc.php, cron.php, and authorize.php. They contain similar code: They bootstrap Drupal, and call one or more hooks for a specific task. Creating those files should be done in specific cases, as reported in [Are there cases where a third-party module would need to use its own file similar to xmlrp.php, cron.php, or authenticate.php?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3390/are-there-cases-where-a-third-party-module-would-need-to-use-its-own-file-similar) It is not your case, but if you decided (subjunctive mood) to create a similar file, it would contain the following code (the code is for Drupal 6):

```
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
echo drupal_render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));
```

There are few cases where creating a file similar to cron.php or update.php is really necessary, such as when you create a soap.php file similar to xmlrpc.php, but for SOAP requests. For cases like yours, you just need to create a module, and implement the necessary hooks.

Answer (score 2):

You should not write code in stand alone php files and call them (Unless you know what you are doing and do it for performance reason, to avoid Drupal bootstrap on a pure external web service call could be one such example).

What you should do instead is to write a module. Use `hook_menu` to define the path that you want to listen for, and create a callback function that will handle incoming requests. Doing it like this will allow you to actually use the Drupal APIs.

You can lookup the hooks and functions you need to use at the [Drupal API reference site](http://api.drupal.org)

Answer (score 0):

To get started check out http://drupal.org/developing/modules which walks you through developing modules in Drupal or check out http://drupal.org/project/examples that shows you how to use the Drupal API.